# Paperclip incorrectly assumes missing.png files for posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using Paperclip 4.1.1 for handling picture uploads to my website.
I have a typical Post model that `has_attached_file :picture`

Pictures upload fine, validate correctly.
The problem is that Paperclip assumes that all posts without pictures are missing them.
So it displays a `missing.png` file for them.

Here's my `Post.rb`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories

    has_attached_file :picture,
                  :styles => {:medium => "350x", :thumb=> "100x" },
                  :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

    validates_attachment_content_type :picture,
                                  :content_type => /\Aimage/,
                                  :size => {:in => 0..2048.kilobytes}

end
```

Is there any way to build a check to not display images for those posts that don't have any pictures associated with them?

Sidenote: I wrote a helper method that displays pictures only if their filename is not `missing.png` I know it is not the correct way of addressing the problem.

Your advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If a post is uploaded without an image, it should show the default_url image.. I'm pretty sure that's working as intended but maybe I misunderstand.. What would you like to display for posts that don't have pictures

Comment: Yes I know that is the intended behavior. I am trying to have the paperclip attachment as an optional field. That way, posts that have pictures will display them, posts that don't have pictures won't display them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the usual behavior of `Paperclip` that if post is uploaded without a picture then image specified in `default_url` would be displayed in its place.

If you wish to avoid this behavior then a work-around would be not to display the picture *if its not present*.

For example: You can do something like this in your view:

```
<%= image_tag @post.picture.url(:thumb) if @post.picture.present? %>
```

This way, if the Post record specified by `@post` has an assigned `picture` field only then that `picture` field would be displayed in the view otherwise not.

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I was trying to do it in a helper in a roundabout way.